# "Не( )совместимых" - раздельно/слитно

Tags: частица-не

*Природа не может изобрести миллиард людей, несовместимых по внешности.*

Пишется ли "несовместимых" раздельно и, если да, почему?

Comment: Вы не могли бы написать краткий отзыв о моем ответе, например: "материал понятен, спасибо"   или  объяснить, что в нем было Вам неясно.    Совсем коротко, можно одним предложением, причем "спасибо" говорить необязательно. Мне просто интересно, насколько он  оказался для Вас полезен.

Answer (score 1):

*Природа не может изобрести миллиард  **несовместимых по внешности людей.***

Основная форма написания слитная, но в постпозиции допускается раздельное написание

*Природа не может изобрести миллиард **людей, не совместимых по внешности.***

Пояснение

1) Совместить (сов.вид) — совместимый — несовместимый.

**Прилагательное** образовано **от глагола сов. вида** и пишется слитно с НЕ, в том числе  при наличии зависимых слов.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

13. Различается написание частицы НЕ с отглагольными прилагательными и причастиями на -мый.

Прилагательные на -мый, как правило, образованы от непереходных глаголов (независимый, непромокаемый, несгораемый и т. п.) или **от глаголов совершенного вида** (неисправимый, неосуществимый, неразрушимый и т. п.).

На эти слова (в том числе и на краткие формы) распространяются общие правила написания НЕ с прилагательными, т. е. **они пишутся слитно и при наличии пояснительных слов**: необитаемый с давних пор остров; нерастворимые в воде кристаллы; неразличимые в темноте фигуры людей.

8. **Раздельное** написание частицы НЕ с прилагательным, имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, **встречается**:

   при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами **после определяемого существительного (иногда):** предприятия, не подведомственные тресту (**при обособлении конструкция с прилагательным приближается по значению к причастному обороту**); ср.: Шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле. — Это черты, не свойственные нашей молодёжи.

Comment: О, я тоже хотел слитный вариант выбрать, но не знал, чем обосновать, — вроде есть зависимые слова. :)

Comment: Можно ли назвать эту конструкцию в постпозиции определительным оборотом?

Comment: А как же эту конструкцию еще можно назвать? Определительный оборот - это распространенное  определение, не более того.  В данном случае определительный оборот выражен прилагательным с зависимым словом.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Пишется ли "несовместимых" раздельно и, если да, почему?
```

Пишется.

Различаются страдательные причастия настоящего времени на -мый и отглагольные прилагательные на -мый.

Первые образуются, как правило, от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида (уважаемый, любимый), вторые — от непереходных глаголов (несмолкаемый) или от глаголов совершенного вида (непогрешимый); многие из них без не не употребляются (невредимый, непоколебимый, нестерпимый и др.).

•   Отглагольные прилагательные на -мый подчиняются правилам правописания не с прилагательными, т. е., в отличие от написания причастий, они пишутся слитно с не:

а) при наличии пояснительных слов: незаменимый по работоспособности сотрудник;

б) в краткой форме: сотрудник незаменим.

3.Пишутся **раздельно** с не отглагольные прилагательные, если в качестве пояснительных слов выступают:

а)отрицательные местоимения или наречия: никогда (никем) не заменимый сотрудник;

б)существительные (или местоимения) **в творительном падеже**, указывающие на производителя действия: не заменимый другими рабочими сотрудник; в этом случае слова на -мый имеют значения причастия.

Исключения составляют слова, которые без не не употребляются и пишутся слитно: никем непобедимый народ.

Так что  раздельное написание возможно: ни с чем не совместимых ингредиентов; никогда не совместимых.

Comment: Вы, вероятно, цитируете Розенталя. но это общие правила по теме, а здесь нужен ответ на на конкретный вопрос, так как приведена конкретная грамматическая структура со своими частными особенностями.

Comment: В ответе есть и о конкретной структуре:Отглагольные прилагательные на -мый подчиняются правилам правописания не с прилагательными, т. е., они пишутся слитно с не: а) при наличии пояснительных слов: незаменимый по работоспособности сотрудник. А кроме того - есть разъяснения, когда эта словоформа пишется раздельно. В чём вопрос? Что не так сказала?

Comment: Пример в заданном вопросе соответствует частному правилу, когда прилагательные могут писаться раздельно с НЕ при наличии зависимых слов (как причастия, а не как прилагательные). Это правило п.8 http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

Comment: Вообще-то  п. 8 - для всех отглагольных прилагательных, а  это пункт 13, 14 - на -мый,  на что я и обратила внимание в ответе и Вам не угодила чем-то.

Comment: Да тут такое дело. В п.13 Розенталь пишет:На эти слова ((на МЫЙ)  распространяются общие правила написания НЕ с прилагательными. Значит, п. 8  к словам на МЫЙ тоже относится, мы должны его рассматривать? Или нет?